# About Trigonometric Transformations in Python

Tags: trigonometry, python

```
R = 6371*1000
lat = 39.05
lon = 40.56
lat = radians(lat)
lon = radians(lon)

x = R * cos(lat) * cos(lon)
y = R * cos(lat) * sin(lon)
z = R *sin(lat)

lon = degrees(atan2(y, x))
lat = degrees(asin(z / R))
```

Hi. 
With above equations i want to find lat again. 
But i shouldn't use the variable z in the last equation. 
How can i achieve this?
Can anyone help me?
Thanks...

Comment: `lat = degrees(acos(sqrt(x**2+y**2)/R))`

Comment: it works. thanks!